# PowerShell append to first available row in a headered column in csv

Tags: powershell, csv, append

Fairly new to PowerShell and having challenges with appending data in the first available row for each headered column in a csv file.

I would like to utilize `foreach` for each column's type of data that will be independent of another column's data. The column headers are `$headers = "Scope", "Drawing", "Submittal", "Database", "Estimate", "Sequence"` with a `foreach` to locate and append their individual items to each column. The current problem that is happening is that because each category/column with its respective `foreach` will add it on a separate row because the previous row already had data appended from another category's/column's data creating a diagonal appended data.

The reason that a separate `foreach` is being used is for each category/column is because the category's are looking for and filtering files independently for each category.

Below is what is happening in the CSV file:

```
| Scope | Drawing | Submittal | Database | Estimate | Sequence |
| ------| ------- |---------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |
| DATA01| empty   | empty     | empty    | empty    | empty    |
| empty | DATA11  | empty     | empty    | empty    | empty    |
| empty | empty   | DATA21    | empty    | empty    | empty    |
| empty | empty   | empty     | DATA31   | empty    | empty    |
| empty | empty   | empty     | empty    | DATA41   | empty    |
| empty | empty   | empty     | empty    | empty    | DATA51   |
```

This is what would be the desired result be for the CSV file:

```
| Scope | Drawing | Submittal | Database | Estimate | Sequence |
| ------| ------- |---------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |
| DATA01| DATA11  | DATA21    | DATA31   | DATA41   | DATA51   |
```

Here is part of the code that is being worked on:

```
# Creates the CSV if it does not already exist
$headers = "Scope", "Mechanical Drawing", "Controls Submittal", "Database", "Estimate", "Sequence of Operations"
$psObject = New-Object psobject
foreach($header in $headers)
{
 Add-Member -InputObject $psobject -MemberType noteproperty -Name $header -Value ""
}
$psObject | Export-Csv $CsvFile -NoTypeInformation

foreach ($file in $ScopeList)
{
    $hash=@{
        "Scope" = $file.Fullname
    }
    $NewItem = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
    Export-Csv $CsvFile -inputobject $NewItem -append -Force
}

foreach ($file in $DrawingList)
{
    $hash=@{
        "Drawing" = $file.Fullname
    }
    $NewItem = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
    Export-Csv $CsvFile -inputobject $NewItem -append -Force
}

foreach ($file in $SubtmittalList)
{
    $hash=@{
        "Submittal" = $file.Fullname
    }
    $NewItem = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
    Export-Csv $CsvFile -inputobject $NewItem -append -Force
}

foreach ($file in $DatabaseList)
{
    $hash=@{
        "Database" = $file.Fullname
    }
    $NewItem = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
    Export-Csv $CsvFile -inputobject $NewItem -append -Force
}

foreach ($file in $EstimateList)
{
    $hash=@{
        "Estimate" = $file.Fullname
    }
    $NewItem = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
    Export-Csv $CsvFile -inputobject $NewItem -append -Force
}

foreach ($file in $SequenceList)
{
    $hash=@{
        "Sequence" = $file.Fullname
    }
    $NewItem = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
    Export-Csv $CsvFile -inputobject $NewItem -append -Force
}
```

The PowerShell version being used is 5.1. Windows 10 OS.

Could someone help me understand how to append on the same row but a different column without erasing another column's existing row of data? Would this be something that could be done with splatting or looking at each variable `${named}List`?

Comment: Are all the lists _aligned_ and have he same count? Eg. item N in `$ScopeList` corresponds to item N in `$SequenceList` etc.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The lists would not be aligned/correspond to each other and might not always have the same count. The count could be 0 for a list. But going back to your example, `$ScopeList` would be independent of `$SequenceList`;both lists have their own filter criteria and file extension types the script is looking for.

Comment: So it's not really a CSV? It's more like a "6 stacked columns next to each other"-kinda file :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Right, a "6 stacked columns next to each other"-type file haha. Originally the script was outputting the lists in a .log file but thinking for future goals, outputting to a CSV would hopefully allow for further data analysis (NLP/K-clustering) in a somewhat consistent tabular/spreadsheet-like format that would be easier to scrape and analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you have 6 arrays of '$file' items that need to be combined into a CSV file.

Then instead of using 6 `foreach` loops, just use one indexed loop and create Objects from the various lists

If all lists have the **same number of items**:

```
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ScopeList.Count; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Scope     = $ScopeList[$i].FullName
        Drawing   = $DrawingList[$i].FullName
        Submittal = $SubtmittalList[$i].FullName
        Database  = $DatabaseList[$i].FullName
        Estimate  = $EstimateList[$i].FullName
        Sequence  = $SequenceList[$i].FullName
    }
}

# now save the result as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\to\TheResult.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If the lists are not all of the same length, you need to do some extra work:

```
# get the maximum number of items of your lists
$maxItems = (($ScopeList, $DrawingList, $SubtmittalList, $DatabaseList, $EstimateList, $SequenceList) | 
            Measure-Object -Property Count -Maximum).Maximum

# loop over the maximum number of items and check each list 
# if the index $i does not exceed the max number of items for that list
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxItems; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Scope     = if ($i -lt $ScopeList.Count)      {$ScopeList[$i].FullName}      else { $null}
        Drawing   = if ($i -lt $DrawingList.Count)    {$DrawingList[$i].FullName}    else { $null}
        Submittal = if ($i -lt $SubtmittalList.Count) {$SubtmittalList[$i].FullName} else { $null}
        Database  = if ($i -lt $DatabaseList.Count)   {$DatabaseList[$i].FullName}   else { $null}
        Estimate  = if ($i -lt $EstimateList.Count)   {$EstimateList[$i].FullName}   else { $null}
        Sequence  = if ($i -lt $SequenceList.Count)   {$SequenceList[$i].FullName}   else { $null}
    }
}

# now save the result as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\to\TheResult.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I had a similar idea last night where alternatively, only the first/top file of the sorted list is selected so that each list would either have 0 or 1 items. The challenge I'm trying to debug is the console is returning an error `Measure-Object : The property "Count" cannot be found in the input for any objects.` from the code `$maxItems = (($ScopeList, $DrawingList, $SubtmittalList, $DatabaseList, $EstimateList, $SequenceList) | 
            Measure-Object -Property Count -Maximum).Maximum`. Doing a `.count` on each list does return a value, not sure why it won't consider them objects.

Comment: @Screamcheese So  at least one of the lists to then is not an array. I'm on mobile now, but will edit tomorrow

Comment: Theo, I figured it out and did a modification to your code. I figured out an alternative solution using your suggestion and creating a new list based on the already established 6 lists because of some `if` statements and filtering. No need to edit tomorrow. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'll post part of the working code below.

Answer (score 0):

Like Theo posted, this mostly worked or brought the intentions closer to the goal.
within each `foreach` loop that created their independent lists, another list was created for filtering the list and used in the below section from Theo.

```
# loop over the maximum number of items and check each list 
# if the index $i does not exceed the max number of items for that list
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxItems; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Scope     = if ($i -lt $ScopeList.Count)      {$ScopeList[$i].FullName}      else { $null}
        Drawing   = if ($i -lt $DrawingList.Count)    {$DrawingList[$i].FullName}    else { $null}
        Submittal = if ($i -lt $SubtmittalList.Count) {$SubtmittalList[$i].FullName} else { $null}
        Database  = if ($i -lt $DatabaseList.Count)   {$DatabaseList[$i].FullName}   else { $null}
        Estimate  = if ($i -lt $EstimateList.Count)   {$EstimateList[$i].FullName}   else { $null}
        Sequence  = if ($i -lt $SequenceList.Count)   {$SequenceList[$i].FullName}   else { $null}
    }
}

# now save the result as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\to\TheResult.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

To get the `$maxItems`, an alternative way was to have a default value of 1 unless a user input has a keyword "list" when they are prompted for other info, which is another challenge on how to limit values to greater than or equal to 1...